# Associating multiple models with a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

let's looking my database schema first, this is a simple structure of database tables as the following.

```
page table (id, title, description, link)
post table (id, body)
list table (id, name)
user table (id, uname, upawd)
tag table  (id, name)

tag_item (tag_id, item_id, item_type)
```

The data row of table `tag_item` will be like this.

```
tag_id   item_id    item_type    
1        1          page 
1        2          page 
1        1          post  
2        1          user 
3        1          list
```

The `item_type` and `item_id` field in `tag_item` table as the related table name and table primary key id, in other words, i want to make use of the tag as the keyword to associating all of tables.
So, how to write the code in individual model class for associating each other with tag.
How to design the association in class model with the way of rails.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you also have a `type` table?

Comment: No `type` table, the `type` field is in tag_item table. That field is mainly for flagging the type of object like `page`. 'post`, `user`, and so on. It means that every object above i said has its tag, we create a tag table for storing all of tags, and need a table like `tag_item` to associate all of objects table and tag table

Comment: But you have `type_id` as well. You better create a `type` (actually in rails table names should be plural, so you need `types`) table like `types(id, name)` and in your `tag_items` table reference it like `tag_items(tag_id, type_id)`.

Comment: I have ever considered to create one more table `type` as you said to store the type information,But i according to the database 3NF to design this database structure. The `item_id` will be stored the data that is primary key of other tables, Maybe i confuse you in question, i fix it. Now, what do you think, should i real create a `type` table?

Comment: Is `item_id` the primary key of the `tag_item` table?

Comment: As i said above , i would use this sql to query the tag of post  ,`SELECT tag.name FROM tag WHERE IN(SELECT ti.tag_id FROM tag_item AS ti WHERE ti.item_id = post.id, ti.item_type = 'post')`, so, according to the sql to make association in model, how to write this code or design with the way of rails. In addition, the item_id is stored the primary key of other table, it is not the primary key of the `tag_item` table

Comment: In addition, the `item_id` is not the primary key of the `tag_item` table, it stores other primary key of other tables like `page_id` `post_id`, `user_id`, `list_id` , etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) to implement the associations:

```
class Type < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_many :tag_items
    has_many :tags, :through => :tag_items
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_many :tag_items
    has_many :types, :through => :tag_items
end
```